# using shell variables in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a use case in which I have to write a shell script as a variable in Jenkins Pipeline and run the same. The short notion of my use case is as follows

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('print Vars'){
            steps{
                script{
                    
                    String script = """ 
                    export pipelineScriptVar='This is a var'
                    echo "${pipelineScriptVar}" """
                    sh script
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the same, I am getting the following error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipelineScriptVar for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:251)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:12)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

but when I remove the echo step and try to grep the environment variable like this.

```
export pipelineScriptVar='This is a var'
env | grep "pipeline"
```

I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are declaring pipelineScriptVar inside a string called script, so when you run this script variable as shell jenkins consider pipelineScriptVar as jenkins variable not a shell variable.

```
So you can use '\' to suppress the string notation of jenkins. Use '\' before ${pipelineScriptVar} like \${pipelineScriptVar}. Hope you find this useful
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use double-quotes(") surrounding your script(or any other String variable) the string is [interpolated](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation) and the variables are replaced by Jenkins. So instead of surrounding with double-quotes surround your script with single-quotes.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('print Vars'){
            steps{
                script{
                    
                    String script = ''' 
                    export pipelineScriptVar='This is a var'
                    echo "${pipelineScriptVar}" '''
                    sh script
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or as Dharani mentioned you can escape the `$` with a backslash. `\$`